# Why isn't product.categories returning my category?

Tags: html, ruby, bigcartel

```
        {% paginate products from products.current by theme.products_per_page %}
          {% for product in products %}

            <div class="{{product.categories}}">

              <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endpaginate %}
```

I'm currently using dugway to develop a theme locally. I have my config.ru file set up to use my store's products.

The above code currently shows the product.name, but I get a rid result for the categories. I'd like each category to show up as a separate class to use for CSS, but get the following:

```
<div class="#<Dugway::Drops::CategoryDrop:0x007fd733b1ca80>#<Dugway::Drops::CategoryDrop:0x007fd733b1ca58>#<Dugway::Drops::CategoryDrop:0x007fd733b1ca30">
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the categories like you did for products.

As each product has a number of categories, do something like this :

```
 {% for category in product.categories %}
  <div class="{{category.name}}">

  </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

But this will create multiple divs with different classes.

Comment: Thanks user972, this spurred a thought: I could put the loop directly in the class, like so.

    <div class="mix {% for category in product.categories %} {{category.name}} {% endfor %}">

That way it doesn't create multiple divs.

Comment: yeah ! that's the way to go

Comment: best is to build a string of all category name/classes and put it in

Comment: Building a string of all category name/classes is another good idea too, but becomes too tough to maintain.